# Running tests sequentially in Selenium - How to setup test setup and teardown

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm setting up my first automation framework, so there's a strong possibility I'm just going about this in entirely the wrong way.

I'm using Selenium, in visual Studio, with NUnit.

I have multiple test methods per class, arranged by functional area.

At the start of each test class, I call my Setup/Teardown file.

The setup initialises my Driver, loads the site and logs in.
My teardown closes the Driver instance.

What I expect to happen is something like this:

- Setup
- Test 1
- Teardown
- Setup
- Test 2
- Teardown

There's a little overhead, but it at least makes the tests somewhat independent.

What's actually happening is

Setup, Test 1 runs, Teardown, Setup. Test 2 starts running, then falls over and complains that the connection to the remote server was refused. Curiously it does work briefly. It logs in, begins to interact with the page, then stops.

Then the teardown occurs.

Is there a different way I should be structuring this?

Comment: show your setup code.. specifically, how are you creating the driver

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're logging in on test 1, and on test 2 you're trying to open a page that requires authentication.

Selenium when closing the browser will clear its cache, meaning if you were logged in anywhere or had stored passwords these will be cleared.

If you provide a bit more information on what the tests are trying to do, maybe some code i might be able to help you further, and on top of that other people may be able to help further.

Comment: OP clearly states that he is logging in as part of setup

Comment: Then OP should clearly log out then @CoreyGoldberg =]